# Mongo C# driver 2.0 - Collection.GetStats is missing

Tags: c#, mongodb

Does anyone know how to get the stats of a collection using the C# driver version 2.0, the documentation says it present in the library MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll but the package never contained such a dll.

I am looking for the api to get statistics of a collection.

Thanks!